# AngularJS: Why doesn't ng-repeat work?

Tags: angularjs

Please look at the following code:

```
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="flexbox" >

    <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="flex-ctrl as ctrl">
      <div id="aside">
        <p ng-repeat="item in ctrl.buttons"> {{item}} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


var app = angular.module("flexbox", []);
app.controller("flex-ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.buttons = ['a','b', 'c'];
}]);
```

I expect to see three `<p>` items. However, it looks like ng-repeat is ignored and I see an empty page.

Do you know what is the problem?

For your convenience:  http://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/yVwWdo

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.buttons` instead of $scope.buttons since you are using `controller as` syntax

```js
var app = angular.module("flexbox", []);
app.controller("flex-ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.buttons = ['a','b', 'c'];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='flexbox'>
    <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="flex-ctrl as ctrl">
      <div id="aside">
        <p ng-repeat="item in ctrl.buttons"> {{item}} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using controller as syntax you can change your ctrl like so:

```
var app = angular.module("flexbox", []);

app.controller("flex-ctrl", [function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.buttons = ['a','b', 'c'];
}]);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is in `$scope`, so you can just loop over it with:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in buttons"> {{item}} </p>
```

Instead of

```
<p ng-repeat="item in ctrl.buttons"> {{item}} </p>
```

---

**[Forked your Codepen here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQbgoz)**